# Recursion to display nested comments with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

How can I make the below code do the same thing but without unncessary repetition? Assuming I want to display only 10 replies to the top-level comment (and then allow them to continue it on another page)

On another forum, someone mentioned you can build them from a single database query or some sort of recursive function. This is what I came up with (limited programming knowledge) but it was said to be inefficient:

```
<?php

// query to get top-level comments, put each row in an array

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    // set variables (such as submitter, date, comment text)
?>

    HTML using variables, without the last </div> tag

    <?php

    // query to get level-1 replies, put each in an array

    foreach ($replies1 as $reply1) {

        // set variables (such as submitter, date, comment text)
    ?>

        HTML using variables without last </div> tag

    <?php 

     // continue more foreach loops, the last having its </div> tag

     ?>

    <?php } $replies1 = array(); // reset ?>

    </div> (to end the container the top-level is in)

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @chris85 This seems to be example code and not real code, which makes it off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: Ah noted, thought this was a simplified version for here.

Comment: hard to say without knowing more, but at a glance, you shouldnt be running queries in foreach loops like that, especially in what appears to be a page template.  You can probably just do a single query before you start rendering the page, in which you use some sort of join to get the top level comments and associate replies.  Anywho, thats all I can really say with the limited information.